# Is there any way to get the input of a HTML form in two PHP files at the same time?

Tags: php, html

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I want the same output in another PHP file besides welcome.php

**EDIT:**
I solved the problem using session variables across php pages.

Comment: Take values in session or cookies.

Comment: no. this has nothing to do with php. an html form can only submit to ONE `action` target a time. If you want the form contents to go elsewhere, then you'd need JS to add a second submission, or have your server-side script push the data to the other php script there.

Comment: Please do some research before asking a question.

Comment: I've done some research and I've read some answers to similar questions, I just don't understand how actually use js or ajax to do any of these things, if any of you could actually show me a simple example that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a JavaScript/JQuery onclick handler on the form by getting rid of the submit button and then replacing it with a button. In the onclick handler you can do ajax requests to two different php files ,thus, solving your current issue.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, I solved the problem using session variables across php pages

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to push the data to the database (from welcome.php as in your form) and read to any number of php files.. for queries refer to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp